# Существуют ли pay-per-click партнерки, кроме AdMob?

Tags: android, реклама

Приложение было забанено AdMob из-за того, что был забанен аккаунт в Google Play. Теперь есть необходимость найти другую рекламную сеть. Предпочтительно с оплатой за клики, а не за просмотры или установки.

Существуют ли таковые? Лично мне пока удалось найти только WapStart. Может быть, есть что-то еще?

Comment: А за что забанили на Google Play?

Comment: @Barmaley, сказали, что я использовал сторонний биллинг внутри приложения. А у меня и не было никакого стороннего биллинга внутри. Была ссылка на сайт, на сайте можно было пополнить счет. Вот они, видимо, к этому и прицепились.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопросы о рекламе и монетизации не соответствуют тематике StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Я использую [эту (startApp)](http://startapp.com/rfnn2ea) рекламную кампанию.

[@BArtWell](/users/13523/bartwell), а также есть еще adbuddiz с их fullBanner рекламой, но мои пользователи быстро возненавидели ее. [StartApp](http://startapp.com/rfnn2ea) восприняли норм.

За регистрацию по ссылку отдельная благодарность! Удачи!

P.S.: меня, кстати, тоже на adMob забанили.(((

Comment: Да, гугловцы в последнее время что называется "жгут"... Спасибо за ссылки. К сожалению, мне нужен только баннер и только PPC. StartApp я пробовал, но он не чистый PPC, в результате получается три дня очень мало, потом один день нормально, потом опять три дня очень мало. Хотелось бы именно чистый PPC.

Comment: Та пожалуйста. Мне не жалко. Если появится РРС, отпишись, пожалуйста, в этой теме. ок?

Comment: @web_alex, главное не забыть :) Пока что, наверное, буду использовать WapStart вместе с StartApp с медиацией от MoPub. Сегодня написал адаптер для первого, если есть желание использовать WapStart+MoPub, могу поделиться.

Comment: @BArtWell, да, я бы хотел поробовать MoPub. 
Помню, что у меня не получилось интегрировать MoPub и AppLift (кстати, есть еще AppLift) в проект. 

Спасибо))) 

p.s.: pastebin.com хорошо подходит для шаринга кода)))

Comment: @web_alex, AppLift, насколько я понимаю, тоже не чистый PPC; там еще и CPA и CPM. Без медиации, боюсь, в нашем случае совсем никак не обойтись. По поводу адаптера, решил все же добавить его к себе на GitHub: https://github.com/bartwell/WapStartMoPubAdaper. Пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [Smaato](https://www.smaato.com/) - я работал с ними, когда ни AdMob не было, ни даже собственно Play Store в России еще толком не работал. До сих пор с одной аппы капают копеечки.

Comment: Спасибо! Добавил его в медиацию, посмотрю, что будет. Хотя, встречал в сети упоминания, что они любят позлобствовать  и побанить разработчиков по неведомой причине. И не совсем понятна модель работы - чистый ли PPC или все же опять с примесями.

Comment: Опробовал Smaato. Они как-то чересчур занижают клики. Например, в отчете медиатора MoPub 38 кликов, а у них 7. Написал им письмо на этот счет - проигнорировали.